# Update Flutter App on Android with `flutter install`

Tags: android, flutter, installation

So I have an App almost finished, which uses a json file located in the documents path of my android device (using the path_provide package). I know that this file will get deleted as soon as I uninstall the app on my phone. For installing the app onto my phone I want to use the command line `flutter install` (I'm on Windows). So if I add more features to my app and `flutter install` again on my android, will it update the device leaving the documents directory just as it is or will it delete that and completely reinstall the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: If you don't already have it installed, then install ADB and on Windows you then must add the folder with ADB to your Path environment variable, so you can easily access it through cmd on Windows (I don't really know about the other platforms). Then you have to create your APK (for example with `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`) and then run `adb install /path/to/your/apk/file.apk`.

Source: mannprerak2's comment on this Github issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40560

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's going to delete the app and the file.

Comment: yeah okay i think i'll build some kind of test application and see how it goes but anyway thanks